# JBPM 6.1.0 KIE workbench evaluation form rendering not properly

Tags: jboss, jbpm, kie

This might be too specific of a question. But I'm really lost. I followed the installation of jBPM 6.1.0 on the website http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html and successfully configured Eclipse, KIE workbench, and WildFly server. When I opened the Evaluation bpm file on KIE workbench as described in the KIE workbench tutorial in the above link, I get the following:
[image: Strange KIE evaluation demo]

Does any experts on jBPM have any advice on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance using Chrome v34? There was a bug in Chrome v34 that caused this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1088898
Updating to a more recent Chrome should fix this.

Comment: Thank you. The chrome version (Version 34.0.1847.131 m) is the problem.